# Algorithm - How to draw a non-perfect diagonal in a pixelated space?

Tags: algorithm, design-patterns, shortest-path, a-star

I'm programming this for my class

[image]

Is a group of squares and I need to paint its with different shapes.

But I don't know how to draw a diagonal just by passing 2 coordinates (x1,y1)(x2,y2)

Does anybody know an algorithm/pseudo-code for this?

P.S. I'm using typescript

Comment: What? Do you need to paint squares or diagonals?

Comment: diagonals pixel by pixel

Comment: Bresenham's algorithm (the line version, not the circle version) draws lines. Treating it as a shortest path algorithm is massive overkill.

Comment: also the search term is **line rasterization** so **DDA** or **Bresenham** is the way to go.

Comment: thanks @harold it's exactly what I needed. Write an answer to up-vote man and to mark as a solution